# AngularJS E-commerce Filters Ordering

Tags: angularjs, e-commerce

I'm working on an e-commerce site that was built using AngularJS. The site gets product data from JSON files to populate everything, including the filters on the category pages.

See the example below (using dummy data)

```
BRAND
Brand A
Brand B
Brand C
Brand D

COLOUR
Red
Green
Purple
Yellow

FLOWERING TIME
8 weeks
10 weeks
7 weeks
9 weeks
```

What we're trying to do is order each of the filters alphabetically, but if I use Angular's orderBy to order results by Brand, it in fact orders the products themselves by brand so products with Brand A will always appear above products with Brand B in the other filters too.

Say P1 is Brand A, Colour Yellow and P2 is Brand B, Colour Red. Then the filter list of Brand will order correctly with Brand A followed by Brand B, but the filter list of Colour will be wrong with Yellow above Red (since Brand A is always at the top).

The problem is that the ordering is done by the products, rather than actual matching results outputted.

Hopefully that makes sense, if anyone can help solve this problem it would very much appreciated!

**EDIT: Code added**

This is the code that loops through the different types of filters and then through the products to get the matching filter criteria.

```
<section data-ng-repeat="(filter, array) in filters" class="widget widget-filter-multiselect" data-ng-class="{ long: array.length > 9 }">
    <h3 class="widget-title">{{ filter }}</h3>
    <div class="search-filter" data-ng-show="array.length > 9">
        <input placeholder="Search {{ filter }}..." type="text" data-ng-model="search"/>
    </div>
    <!-- /.search-filter -->
    <ul class="checklist">
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in array | filter: search">
            <a data-ng-class="{ active: checkActive(filter, item) }" data-ng-click="toggleFilter(filter, item); buildPath()">
                <i class="unchecked fa fa-square-o"></i>
                <i class="checked fa fa-check-square"></i>
                <span data-ng-bind-html="item | highlightfilter:search"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

The controller is an absolute behemoth so I'm not sure which bits of it to put here?

Comment: It's hard to see without at least some mock data and or code. Do you have any code that would be easily mocked out so that it is easier to understand what is going on?

Comment: can you give us a sample of your code ?

Comment: It's difficult to add code because there is simply so much. I've added the code from the template file, but the controller is a mass of functions so not sure what bits would be useful?

Comment: It will help to post the JSON of the item itself.  Probably you can use a custom filter to strip out the name from the field if that is what the problem is